# initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have a sub-project under my project.

In **sub-project**, I have a protocol:

```
public protocol MyProtocol {
    func print()
}
```

In **sub-project** I have also a `School` struct which accepts a instance which conforms to `MyProtocol` in initializer:

```
public struct School {
    var name: String
    var delegator: MyProtocol
    public init(name: String, delegate: MyProtocol) {
        self.name = name
        self.delegator = delegate
    }
}
```

In my project (which imports sub-project), I have a `UIViewController`, I have a extension to it which conforms to `MyProtocol`.

```
class MyVC: UIViewController {
  ...
  override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
     // ERROR: 'School' initializer is inaccessible due to 'internal' protection level
     let school = School(name: "John", delegate: self)
  }

}
```

I extend the `MyVC` to conform with `MyProtocol`:

```
extension MyVC : MyProtocol {
    public func print() {
        // printing...
    }
}
```

Why I get that error? How to solve it?

Comment: your code works for me just fine

Comment: first thing I would try is to clean and then rebuild the project.. maybe some cache thing

Comment: I've tested too. It seems ok

Comment: Oh, sorry, there is one thing missing in my code snippet, I will update my code very soon.

Comment: it works , but he says it exists in a sub project

Comment: I updated my code.

Comment: Do you mean School struct is in a framework

Comment: It is working for me, even with the `MyProtocol` and `School` as sub projectes...

Comment: School is not in a framework, it is in a subproject created by me as well. My project has a dependency on sub-project.  Sub-project is nested under My project.

Comment: OK... I don't know why, clearning & re-build didn't make the error disappear, but now it suddenly disappear....I will close this post. Xcode issue.